# Why am I getting an Error 1309 : Error reading from file..... when attempting to use a .msi generated by InstallShield in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield-le, installshield-2012

Error 1309 : Error reading from file.....

I am using VS2013 - with latest download of InstallShield Limited Edition

From VS2013 -> Solution Explorer -> Installshield Project -> Uninstall/Install: everything is fine.

If I run the installer file (right click .msi file->uninstall/install) from the directory it is compiled in everything is fine.

If I copy the .msi file anywhere else I get the above error UNLESS I copy the 'program files' directory that is also created in the DISK1 folder of installshield project.

I thought this was all supposed to be packaged into 1 file (isn't that the purpose of InstallShield?)

This question was originally posted on the flexera forum, but no one seems to be responding to questions on that forum:

https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?214260-Error-1309-Error-reading-from-file

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks,
JB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it.  When you have your InstallShield LE project ready to Build, Go into Build, Configuration Manager and change the build to SingleImage.  Next do a Build.  When you navigate the folders to where the CD_ROM folder is, you will see a new folder called SingleImage.  As you go through that you will find the single MSI file that contains all folders.  No more issues with Error 1309.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should also ensure that the 254 character limit for the files' local url is not exceeded